# Why do pointers use -> instead of .?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does C have a distinction between -> and . ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813865/why-does-c-have-a-distinction-between-and)

Lets say that I have this structure:

```
struct movies
{
    string title;
    int year;
} my_movie, *ptrMovie;
```

Now I access `my_movie` like this: `my_movie.year = 1999;` 
Now to access a pointer I must do this: `ptrMovie->year = 1999;`

Why do pointers use the `->` operator and normal data types use the `.` operator? Is there any reason they couldn't both use the `.` operator?

Comment: ... because it would be confusing?  Different operation -> different operator.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813865/why-does-c-have-a-distinction-between-and

Comment: Oops...it didn't show up when I searched for it. Sorry.

Comment: I suppose the 'duplicate' is a C question and not a C++ question but as much of the reason why C++ is grammar is like it is is because that's how C does it. Some answers in the other question also address C++ compatibility as well, though.

Comment: To be fair, if we look at C++ instead of C, another reason is that `operator->` needs to be distinct from operator. for implementing smart pointer classes (`operator->` must be overloadable to thunk through to the pointee, but `operator.` must be separate and non-overloadable to allow accessing methods on the smart pointer object itself).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The . operator accesses a member of a structure and can operate only on structure variables. 
If you want to do this to a pointer, you first need to dereference the pointer (using `*`) and then access the member (using `.`). Something like

```
(*ptrMovie).year = 1999
```

The `->` operator is a shorthand for this.

Comment: "The . operator accesses a member of a structure and can operate only on structure variables."??? really? how about class member variables?

Comment: I stand corrected. The OP mentioned structures and I confined my response to C (which doesn't have classes).

Comment: @Noufal, yes, but the question is tagged C++ which has both structs and classes

Comment: Glen, there's no difference between a structure and a class outside their definition.

Comment: In C++ a structure is a type of class. `.` operates on all types of class including structures and unions.

Comment: @Glen. Yup. My mistake. I'm not very familiar with C++ and that narrowed my answer as well. Your comment clarifies the point though. Thanks.

Comment: @avakar, Charles, yes, I know that.  The answer however states that the . operator can only be used on structs.  This is obviously incorrect, so I'm just trying to clarify the answer for others.

Comment: @Glen: The `class` keyword creates a struct.  However, some classes are not structs, they are unions, and the member access operators are usable with those too.

Answer (score 4):

The `.` operator is only valid for a struct or class. A pointer is not a struct or class, so you need to dereference your pointer to get the struct/class it is pointing to like this

```
(*ptrMovie).year
```

The member operator `.` has a higher precedence than the dereference operator `*`, so you need to enclose the dereferencing operation in parenthesis. Or you could do this

```
ptrMovie->year
```

Both are equivalent. The '->' operator is a shortcut for dereferencing your pointer and then accessing a struct member. It is less typing and a little nicer to use in my opinion. Apparently most people agree with me because that is the standard way to access struct members from a pointer to the struct in most code that I've seen. You especially appreciate the difference when you have to do multiple levels of indirection:

```
ptrToStruct->memberPtr->subMemberPtr->subsubPtr->subsubsubPtr->x

(*(*(*(*(ptrToStruct).memberPtr).subMemberPtr).subsubPtr).subsubsubPtr).x
```

Both of those statements are equivalent, but the first is easier to work with.

Comment: ". is only valid for a struct"??? really? how about classes?

Comment: Aside from the default protection (public for struct, private for class), class and struct are interchangeable in C++.

Comment: @KeithB, yes, I know.  However the answer implies otherwise.  Maybe my comment wasn't particularly clear while trying to clarify that

Comment: Yeah...I should have said "struct or class" Even though they are functionally the same thing in C++.

Comment: How about `union`?  In fact, it's valid for all classes (which are types introduced by the class-key `class`, `struct`, or `union`).

Answer (score 2):

If they both used . how could you differentiate between the pointer and the actual object?
To me:

```
->
```

Reminds me of an arrow which points to something, so I find it great that -> is used.

Instead of typing `(*myPointer).` it is simplier to use `myPointer->`