# Why is there a different operator for member access/element selection on pointers?

Tags: c++, c, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does C have a distinction between -> and .?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813865/why-does-c-have-a-distinction-between-and)

Compilers are smart enough to know if the left side operand is a pointer or a reference. Why are there two different operators (. and ->) for member access?

Is it to make the indirection explicit? For legibility? Was there something about the available hardware when C was designed that made a strong case for those operations to be easily distinguished when reading source code?

I've read about it simply being a shorthand syntax for `(*ptr).member`, but is `ptr.member` ever valid when ptr is a pointer? Why can't `ptr.member` "just work" as `ptr->member` if ptr is a pointer?

Comment: Yes, exact duplicate. I should have searched more.

Comment: a) "Why can't ptr.member "just work" as ptr->member if ptr is a pointer?" it could, in C, but doesn't for historical reasons. b) In C++ it would be an incompatible change due to operator overloading. c) Note that function pointers are automatically dereferenced ... `p()` is equivalent to `(********p)()` d) Use a more modern language like rust or D.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an answer, but one place this distinction is taken advantage of is with **smart pointers** and container **iterators**.

In both cases, the `.` operator is used to operate on the object itself, while the `->` is used to operate on the object that is contained within.